# How to get the list of songs using Spotify in Swift3 iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, spotify

I am developing an music App using Swift3 language. Where user will have popup option to show the list of Songs using Music Library & Spotify. I can able to display the song lists from Music Library to my tableview. Now I have to get the playlists from Spotify. So, I added the App in `accounts.spotify.com` and I can play the songs one by one using `SPTAudioStreamingController.sharedInstance().metadata` but full song lists are not coming.

I follow this links: https://github.com/Sethmr/SpotifyInSwift & https://medium.com/@elonrubin/ios-spotify-sdk-swift-3-0-tutorial-b629af4b889d & https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-ios-sdk/tutorial/

The problem is How can I get the list of Spotify Songs. If anyone have some idea, please suggest me. Thank You!

Comment: Working with playlists is a big topic, you might want to familiarise yourself with https://spotify.github.io/ios-sdk/Classes/SPTPlaylistList.html and the other classes connected to playlists. If you have some code that you're unable to make work, come back and people might be able to help you.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, It seems I need to call this + playlistsForUser:withAccessToken:callback: method to get the playlist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is one more to try [here](https://github.com/Daltron/Spartan)

There are some more controls

**Get an album:**

```
_ = Spartan.getAlbum(id: albumId, market: .us, success: { (album) in
    // Do something with the album    
}, failure: { (error) in
    print(error)      
})
```

**Get several tracks:**

```
_ = Spartan.getTracks(ids: trackIds, market: .us, success: { (tracks) in
    // Do something with the tracks
}, failure: { (error) in
    print(error)
})
```

Try it, may help you
https://github.com/Daltron/Spartan

Also go through [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44182997/spotify-ios-sdk-swift-display-all-playlists-20)([Samantha's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44182997/spotify-ios-sdk-swift-display-all-playlists-20?answertab=active#tab-top))

```
SPTPlaylistList.playlists(forUser: session.canonicalUsername, withAccessToken: session.accessToken, callback: { (error, response) in
                self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                if let listPage = response as? SPTPlaylistList, let playlists = listPage.items as? [SPTPartialPlaylist] {
                    self.playlists = playlists    // or however you want to parse these
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                    if listPage.hasNextPage {
                        self.getNextPlaylistPage(currentPage: listPage)
                    }
                }
            })
```

**Update :**

Refer this **[sample code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/48y27ijft3ytsja/TestSpotifyNew.zip?dl=0)** also

Comment: Thank you @manukv, Can you please tell me how can I get session.canonicalUsername?

Comment: canonicalUsername is a property of SPTSession class

Comment: the same session from where you getting the accessToken

Comment: Okay, I got that property. Let me try this.

Comment: I have got my CanonicalUserName using SPTSession class, After implementing above method I am getting <SPTPlaylistList: 0x1c4281ae0>: ------ of 0 items as response... Seems like list is empty.

Comment: please make sure that the playlist has tracks in it or try to create a new playlist and repeat the method. If it is helped to you please consider to accept my answer. thank you

Comment: Hi @manukv I got the Playlists as: [<SPTPartialPlaylist: 0x6000002bf7a2>: Play2 [3 tracks] (spotify:user:my_app:playlist:2FPwFoPmTkj8piyD7tWPayERK), <SPTPartialPlaylist: 0x6000002bf8c0>: Play1 [3 tracks] (spotify:user:my_app:playlist:4tT8RrnvGGLhht80dGFRyXYZX)] how can I get playlist details like name, id, album or uri..?

Comment: you can get name, id etc from SPTPartialPlaylist itself pls refer this (api documentation) https://spotify.github.io/ios-sdk/Classes/SPTPartialPlaylist.html

Comment: Can check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54996772/get-the-list-of-genre-and-their-respected-songs-of-spotify-in-swift-ios