# How to get current user's playlist from Spotify

Tags: ios, swift, spotify

I am trying to implement Spotify integration with current user's playlist to display it in my tableview. I have integrated with login and access token everything works fine. I have gone through stack overflow link:- [How to get the list of songs using Spotify in Swift3 iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47813383/how-to-get-the-list-of-songs-using-spotify-in-swift3-ios) but didn't work for me.

Then to get print for canonicalUsername as below, its showing nil value

```
SPTUser.requestCurrentUser(withAccessToken:(SPTAuth.defaultInstance().session.accessToken)!) { (error, data) in
        guard let user = data as? SPTUser else { print("Couldn't cast as SPTUser"); return }
        let userId = user.canonicalUsername
})
```

I have even tried this link [Spotify iOS SDK Swift display all (!) playlists (20+)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44182997/spotify-ios-sdk-swift-display-all-playlists-20?answertab=active#tab-top) due to beginner may be it also didn't work for me. Is there any way to get Spotify's current user-id? How could I show the current user's playlist in my table view?

Comment: Have you tried getting the canonical username from the session? `SPTAuth.defaultInstance().session.canonicalUsername`? (Assuming this is using their old SDK)

Comment: @Samantha, i will try try this one, if u have could u please share the code for getting current user's playlist and display it in tableview.

Comment: Once you get this working, what have you tried to get it to display in a `tableView`?

Comment: @Samantha, I managed to get the playlist printed like  
                      code //  if let playlist = playList as? SPTPartialPlaylist {
                            print( playlist.uri!)  // playlist uri. How could I use this uri and play in AVPlayer..

Comment: Your question keeps changing. I suggest you search for Spotify/Swift tutorials and then, if it still isn’t solved, post **one** specific question with code you’ve already tried. Assuming you’re using the sdk at https://github.com/spotify/ios-streaming-sdk, the headers inside the frameworks are fairly well-documented, and you’ll find you’re actually provided with a streaming player by Spotify itself. There are many many decent tutorials online and previously-asked questions on SO that will get you to a point where you can at least give us an attempt at solving the problem, and we can help you.

Comment: https://medium.com/@elonrubin/ios-spotify-sdk-swift-3-0-tutorial-b629af4b889d, for example, should show you how to stream through Spotify. In combination with the linked answer in your question (how to get all songs on a playlist), it should give you a place to start streaming your playlist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go through online tutorial in youtube :- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KLsP7oThgHU&t=1s for latest version in 2019.

Download full source code with Spotify Integration + search options + default Spotify url and fetch current user's playlist and play in our native iOS App 
Source:- https://github.com/azeemohd786/Spotify-Demo

Based on your question the solution to get print canonicalUsername or current user's id try as below,

```
 SPTUser.requestCurrentUser(withAccessToken: session.accessToken) { (error, data) in
                    guard let user = data as? SPTUser else { print("Couldn't cast as SPTUser"); return }
                    let userID = user.canonicalUserName

                 print(userID!)
                 }
```

Then to get current user's playlist and play in ur device, first call the SPT Delegate in your view controller like and then function call,

```
class PlayVC: UIViewController, SPTAudioStreamingDelegate, SPTAudioStreamingPlaybackDelegate {
func audioStreamingDidLogin(_ audioStreaming: SPTAudioStreamingController) {
        let playListRequest = try! SPTPlaylistList.createRequestForGettingPlaylists(forUser: session.canonicalUsername, withAccessToken: session.accessToken)
        Alamofire.request(playListRequest)
            .response { response in
                let list = try! SPTPlaylistList(from: response.data, with: response.response)

                for playList in list.items  {
                    if let playlist = playList as? SPTPartialPlaylist {
                        print( playlist.name! ) // playlist name
                        print( playlist.uri!)    // playlist uri
                      // self.tableView.reloadData()// if u want to display playlist name and other stuffs like so..
                        SPTAudioStreamingController.sharedInstance().playSpotifyURI("\(playlist.uri!)", startingWith: 0, startingWithPosition: 10) { error in
                            if error != nil {
                                print("*** failed to play: \(error)")
                                return
                            }
                        }
                        }}}

    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for sharing the tutorial and source code.Great... It worked though....solved my problem.

Comment: @Aleesha, just through the youtube tutorial link and then use the source code to get ur stuffs.. Nice to hear it worked 4 u.